# fscanf can't read the first integer of my file input in C but reads the rest

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

My program needs to read input from a file. The file has a format "int int int" and then some asterisks to indicate that you need to stop reading there. I want to store them in an array of struct and I did. But it seems like my program can't read the very first integer of the input file. I checked it with printf and I can't do anything about it. Help please. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct points{
    int i;
    int x;
    int y;
};
int main(){
    int lines = 0;
    char c, e;
    int i, j, x ,y, a, b, temp ;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fp != NULL){
        while ((e = fgetc(fp)) != '*'){                     
            if (c == '\n'){
                lines++;
            }
            fscanf(fp, "%d%d%d", &i, &x, &y);
            struct points pt[lines];
            for (j = 0; j <= lines; j++){
                pt[j].i = i;
                pt[j].x = x;
                pt[j].y = y;
                printf("%d ", pt[j].i);
            }
            for (a = 0; a<=lines; a++){
                for (b = a + 1; b <= lines; b++){
                    if (pt[a].x > pt[b].x){
                        temp = pt[a].x;
                        pt[a].x = pt[b].x;
                        pt[b].x = temp;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }           
    }
    else{
        printf("Cannot open File!\n");      
    }
    printf("lines = %d\n", lines);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (j = 0; j <= lines; j++){` should be `for (j = 0; j < lines; j++){` IMHO. 2) BTW: do you intend to first count the '\n' s and then rewind and read the actual lines ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
        while ((e = fgetc(fp)) != '*') {                             
            if (c == '\n'){
                lines++;
            }
            fscanf(fp, "%d%d%d", &i, &x, &y);
```

will read the first character and throw it away if it is NOT an asterisk, and will then attempt to read 3 integers AFTER that first character it threw away.  If that first character was a digit, then it will look like you 'lost' (part of) the first number.

You also have the problem that you seem to be trying to read the values into a block-local array `pt` that exists for a single iteration of the `while` loop (so its recreated with no (garbage) contents each iteration), and then you want to use it after the loop where it is out of scope (so this code won't compile).

What you want is probably something more like:

```
#define MAX_POINTS  100
struct points pt[MAX_POINTS];
int i = 0;
while (i < MAX_POINTS && 3 == fscanf(fp, "%d%d%d", &pt[i].i, &pt[i].x, &pt[i].y)) {
    printf("%d ", pt[i].i);
    i++;
}
for (int a = 0; a <= i; a++) {
    for (int b = a+1; b <= i; b++) {
        :
```

Note that this reads integers up until it finds something that doesn't look like an integer (such as an asterisk, but could be anything else, including an end-of-file), rather than reading until it finds an asterisk.  If you want to read until you see an asterisk, you need to decide what to do with anything that is neither an asterisk or an integer.

**Edit**

for your alternate question of how to read numbers up to `***` and then read more numbers after them (and possibly more stars), you could use something like:

```
int val;
char buffer[20];
do {
    /* start of a group */
    while (1 == fscanf(fp, "%d", &val)) {
        /* read an integer within a group */
    }
    /* fp is at EOF or something not an integer. */
    /* so read it and loop if its '***' */
} while (1 == fscanf(" %19[*]", &buf) && !strcmp(buf, "***"));
```

Comment: Let's say my input.txt isa something like this:
1 2 3
2 3 4
5 6 7
***
1 3 4
2 3 5
3 4 7
***end of input***
And I want to do something to the integers before the ***, and I would do it as well to the integers after that. In short, the *** separates the input to several cases. How would I implement a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the format string `"%d %d %d"` instead of `"%d%d%d"` (i.e. with spaces)?

Also, there are several other problems I see:

1. You use a `while` loop to find the first `'*'` in the line, but then you ask `fscanf` to parse 3 `int`s starting at that location. It may not be able to find an `int` by looking at a `'*'`...
2. You also declare the variable `struct points pt[lines];` in the middle of a block; that is not valid C syntax.

Once you fix these things, the problem may be fixed.

Comment: the spaces will make no difference -- `%d` impliciatly skips whitespace automatically.

Comment: Don't answer a question with a question. Also, point out all the errors. For example: The use of `e` vs. `c`; the return value of `fgetc` is an `int`; should check for `EOF` return value of `fgetc` instead of `*`; the need to call `ungetc` if the character is not a newline; the need to check the result of `fscanf` when it is parsing stars instead; how `pt` is local to the `while` loop; how the loops write one beyond the end of the `pt` array. There may be others you can find.

Comment: @jxh also, you could just write an answer :)

Comment: @feralin: I am just trying to help you out. Generally, answers that are a one line question will get flagged as not an answer. And, I am maxed out for points for the day.